I have set a Lightning App as Default for a Profile, but it still doesn't show when that user first logs in
I am trying to have users with the profile "Custom: Support Profile" default to the lightning app "Service Console" upon login.  I have created a user "Profile, Support" to test this:
I have assigned this as the default app for this profile:

But they still log directly into Service as seen here:

They do have access to service console, but I cannot figure out why it does not default to service console upon login.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

How are you getting to that Custom App Settings section - are you still in Classic?  What do you see when you go to Setup > Lightning App Manager, opening the app and going to User Profiles?  Also, do you have Enhanced Profile User Interface enabled in Setup > User Management Settings?

@DavidCheng Thanks for the response.  I am in Lightning.  I don't see Lightning App Manager; when I search "lightning app" in setup it only shows Lightning App Builder.  I did not have Enhanced Profile User Interface enabled.  I tried enabling this and unassigning and reassigning the Lightning App as default, but the issue was not resolved.

As per the help article,

Assigning a default app will only allow Users to see the app when they
login to Salesforce for the first time. However, when a User switches
Apps during his session, logs out and logs back in, the User is taken
back to the last App he/she was in. Please upvote on this Idea:
Default App (Landing App)

Also, check this known issue.

Profile Default App does not load for a user's very first login to Salesforce when a custom Lightning App is added


Thanks, this seems to be the answer.  Also to note for anyone else who runs into this, if you login as another user using System Administrator privileges, it doesn't change the app they see when they login, you have to do this actually logged in as the user.
